# the form [input] width is not the same in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a table form, in Firefox/Chrome it looks perfect, but in IE it looks not equal. Below is the table in IE, the form in the left is longer than in the right (i show border to make it easier to see). the CSS for the form is using `width:100%` and if i change it, the left form will always be longer.
Is there any simple way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you share your code it would be easier to provied an accurate answer. However I will try to help with something anyway.

If you are setting the width of the INPUT element to 100%, it will use the 100% of the space available given by the parent element. (In this case, it may probably be the TD element.)

So it seems that your problem may reside in the TD width rather than in the INPUT width.

On a side note I recommend using tables only for tabular data. There are other ways to layout your form without using the TABLE element.

Further advice can be given with your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i fix it by myself manually set the width